Use https in url() with Twig
In Twig, url() returns an absolute path with "http" schema.
How can I configure url() in Twig to use "https://" instead of "http://"?

Use https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html to accept your load balancer's X-Forwarded-Proto value correctly.

Instead of patching http, I would like is to get rid of the http protocol and only use https.
For some obscure reason, url() considers that I want http.
Is it possible for url() function to produce https links?

Does that help you? https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/routing.html#forcing-https-on-generated-urls

@user3429660 I'm not suggesting patching anything. url() typically thinks you want http on a https site when you haven't correctly set up your load balancer as a trusted proxy.

In my setup, CloudFront terminates the SSL connection and is configured to forward requests to port 80. There is no 'Forwarded' header, only the "Host" header. Symfony interpreted this as an insecure connection, and I couldn’t find a way to override the protocol.
I found the solution here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#overriding-configuration-behind-hidden-ssl-termination

Cloudfront sends an X-Forwarded-Proto header.
